# Using proc freq to cross tabulate within same ID that has 2 occurences

Tags: sas

I have a data set where ID's have 2 different occurences on the same day. There are about 10 different occurences. I want to cross tabulate the occurences using proc freq or proc tabulate & find how many times each instance occurs on the same day. I want my table to look something like this

```
Frequency  occ1 occ2 occ3 occ4 occ5 occ6    
occ1        2    0    0     1   4    0
occ2        1    0    0     0   0    0
occ3        3    0    0     0   0    0
occ4        0    5    3     0   3    0
occ5        0    2    4     0   5    0
occ6        1    5    4     2   1    2
```

My data looks something like this

```
data have;
input id occurrence ;
datalines;
id1  occ3           
id1  occ2
id2  occ1
id2  occ6
id3  occ2
id3  occ4
etc...
```

i tried

```
proc freq data=have;
    tables occurrence*occurence ;
    run;
```

but not having any luck.
I have tried other variations & using by ID but it gives every single ID individually & i have about 200 ID numbers.

Thanks!

Comment: For occurrence pair counts do you want the output to be a symmetric matrix (order independent), or does the first occ in an id correspond to row and the second to a column?

Comment: why are the sql and stack-overflow tags here?

Answer (score 1):

Reform data so a tabulation of ordered pairs can be done.

```
data have;
  call streaminit(2022);
  do id = 1 to 20;
    topic = rand('integer', 10); output;
    topic = rand('integer', 10); output;
  end;
run;

data stage;
  do until (last.id);
    set have;
    by id;
    row = col;
    col = topic;
  end;
run;

ods html file='pairfreq.html';
title "Ordered pair counts";
proc tabulate data=stage;
  class row col;
  table row='1st topic in id pair',col='2nd topic in id pair'*n='';
run;
ods html close;
```

[image]

Comment: Richard, could you please kindly tell me, how does `row=col; col=topic;` works?

Comment: Using a presumption of each id value having a pair of rows for the topics the loop will iterate twice. The `row=col; col=topic;` inside the loop will *cascade* values through the variables, so at iteration 2 row will be value from 1st item (topic) in pair, and col the 2nd.